# How to create contact form in PimCore

Tags: pimcore

I'm starting out with PimCore and would like to create a simple contact form (or any frontend form to save some data into the db) but struggling to find any resources on it (including PimCore official docs).

Any ideas on how this can be done would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://pimcore.com/en/developers/marketplace/dachcom-digital/formbuilder_e5462

Go to Settings => Form Builder Settings and create your form (Make sure your spam protection is covered).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it seems [Symfony forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) is the way Pimcore does it (with some small differences (createView needed on $form):

```
return $this->render('content/hello.html.twig', [
        'animal' => $animal,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
```